# ubuntu pycharm cannot be attached to process

Tags: pycharm

On ubuntu18.04, I use pycharm2020.1.2 to debug a multi-process project developed with python 3.6.9. When I perform an additional process, a connection timeout occurs and the additional process server stops directly.

Comment: This is happening also to me. I'm getting: Connection to Python debugger failed: Accept timed out